# How to seprate this function for each radio having different name

Tags: jquery

hi please help me how can i separate this function for each different radio name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='sharedprices']").change(function() {
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + this.value).show();
    }).filter(function(){
        return this.checked;
    }).change();
});  

<div class="shared-price-change-main">
                            <ul>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="sharedprices" checked="checked" value="standard1"  /> 1 Month <b>$1.99</b>/mo</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="sharedprices" value="standard2" /> 6 Months <b>$1.99</b>/mo</li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="sharedprices" value="standard3" /> 12 Months <b>$1.99</b>/mo</li>
                            </ul>  

                                              <div id="myRadioGroup" class="shareddetailsplan">
                                <div id="standard1" class="desc">
                                <label>You Save 0</label>
                                <div class="shared-page-tables-4colmns-button"><a href="#">Order Now</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="standard2" class="desc">
                                <label>You Save 5%</label>
                                <div class="shared-page-tables-4colmns-button"><a href="#">Order Now</a></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="standard3" class="desc">
                                <label>You Save 10%</label>
                                <div class="shared-page-tables-4colmns-button"><a href="#">Order Now</a></div>
                                </div>
                    </div>  </div>
```

actually this thing will be used multiple times on the page but for each different plan but using this code for different plan, this code only checked the last one but i need it to separate this for every different plan that's the main problem

Comment: Can you show some HTML. How manu different names are there? Why not just `$(':radio').change....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loot at this [`:radio Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

```
$("input:radio").change(function() { ...
```

Comment: Thank but but how can i seprate You Save % and Order now button for each radio group actually "the plans repeats multiple times for 3 time or 4 time and I require these 3 plan terms for each plan please help